# How do I set up glowing bear for Ubuntu servers?

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10, irc

So glowing -bear got a recent snap.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/call-for-testing-snapcraft-2-35/2880/2

How do I set it up for ubuntu servers ?

please keep in mind that I already have vpn in my menu bar under VPN connections, although I have to initate this every time I logon.

thanks - I am a complete noob with networks.

Answer (score 0):

Glowing Bear is probably not something you want to set up in your server. The idea is usually to have weechat in a server that is working 24/7, so you don't miss anything from IRC chats. And use Glowing Bear from your desktop or phone.

So, to install weechat on your server, just do:

```
sudo apt install weechat
```

Then, you should configure weechat to use a certificate. This is copied from https://www.glowing-bear.org/:

> Setup: If you want to use an encrypted session you first have to set
>   up the relay to use TLS. You basically have two options: a self-signed
>   certificate is easier to set up, but requires manual security
>   exceptions. Using a certificate that is trusted by your browser
>   requires more setup, but offers greater convenience later on and does
>   not require security exceptions. You can find a guide to set up
>   WeeChat with a free trusted certificate from StartSSL [here](https://4z2.de/2014/07/06/weechat-trusted-relay). Should you
>   wish to use a self-signed certificate instead, execute the following
>   commands in a shell on the same host and as the user running WeeChat:
>
> $ mkdir -p ~/.weechat/ssl $ cd ~/.weechat/ssl $ openssl req -nodes
>   -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout relay.pem -x509 -days 365 -out relay.pem -sha256 -subj "/CN=localhost/"
>
> If WeeChat is already running, you can reload the certificate and
>   private key and set up an encrypted relay on port 9001 with these
>   WeeChat commands:
>
> /set relay.network.password yourpassword /relay sslcertkey /relay add
>   ssl.weechat 9001